How to publish joint state of a robot to another robot?
I am totally new in teleoperation, and I am stuck on how to publish joint state of a robot to another robot? I am using Franka Emika, and Franka_ros has a franka_hw that reads joint state, but this is not a node. I am thinking of writing a publisher node, somehow link to this JointStateInterface to read the joint states, anyone know how to do this?


What have you tried and what didn't work?
